# p5.js control the amount of frames I play

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to control the amount of times `draw()` is being called, basically lets immagine that i have that basic code:

```
var e = 1;

function setup() {
    window.canvas = createCanvas(200, 200);
}

function draw() {
    fill(255, 255, 0);
    ellipse(50 + e, 50, 30);
    e++;
}
```

and I want to make a function `moveOneStep()` that will active `draw()` once, so let's assume I'm doing a for loop 5 times, then draw will be called 5 times and the circle will move 5 steps ( pixels ) to the right,

how can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to fixe the framerate in your code or to call `draw()` function in a specific time? If it's the case I don't think you can because the draw function is, as mentioned in the documentation

> the draw() function continuously executes the lines of code contained inside its block until the program is stopped or noLoop() is called

But if you want to fixe the frame rate u can call the `frameRate(number)` in the setup() function. So, now if you want to have `draw()` called 30 times per second
(or 30 fps for a gaming reference) your code will look like this.

```
var e = 1;

function setup() {
    window.canvas = createCanvas(200, 200);
    frameRate(30);
}

function draw() {
    fill(255, 255, 0);
    ellipse(50 + e, 50, 30);
    e++;
}
```

Check the [dcumentation](https://p5js.org/reference/) for further references.

Happy coding ^^.

Comment: yeah but I could do something like noLoop() and call manually `draw()`

Comment: I mentioned that too, but it seems like your problem is unclear for me, can you elaborate, please.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of controlling the number of times that `draw` gets called you can control what happens inside of `draw`.

To use `draw` in a way that allows user interaction and works well with the p5js lib you can listen for user interaction with a `keyPressed` method and record what the user is telling the system to do. Back in the `draw` method you can update positions and then render the sketch.

This approach breaks the direct connection between frame rate and user interaction. For example we could slow the frame rate down but still allow the user to click buttons as quickly as the key board would allow. Positions would still get adjusted and draw would catch up.

Here is a simple example that allows a user to move a circle with a ,s, d, w keys or up, down, left, right arrow keys.

```js
var xPos = 0;
var yPos = 0;
var moveRightCount = 0;
var moveLeftCount = 0;
var moveUpCount = 0;
var moveDownCount = 0;

function setup() {
    window.canvas = createCanvas(200, 200);
}
function keyPressed() {
   if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW || keyCode === 68) {
    moveRightCount+=1;
  } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW || keyCode === 65) {
    moveLeftCount+=1;
  } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW || keyCode === 83) {
    moveDownCount+=1;
  }else if (keyCode === UP_ARROW || keyCode === 87) {
    moveUpCount+=1;
  } else if (keyCode === 70){
    
   // console.log(keyCode);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  if (moveRightCount > 0){
    xPos++;
    moveRightCount--;
  }
  if (moveLeftCount > 0){
    xPos--;
    moveLeftCount--;
  }
  if (moveUpCount > 0){
    yPos--;
    moveUpCount--;
  }
  if (moveDownCount > 0){
    yPos++;
    moveDownCount--;
  }
    fill(255, 255, 0);
    ellipse(50 + xPos, 50 + yPos, 30);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Now if you have a method called `moveOneStep()` it could adjust the appropriate move count and as draw gets called according to its `frameRate` the image would be moved. Say we call `moveOneStep()` in a loop that executes 5 times the image would be moved one position per execution of `draw` 5 times.